# Circular references, objective - c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had this problem with import statements with my own classes using forward declarations to fix that.  I have a method that uses type CTFramesetterRef.  So I needed to add the CoreText framework.  If I declare the method in my .h file, do I just

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
```

in my .h file and not my .m file.  Are there any hard and fast rules for this?  Sometimes I see code that has it in the .m, sometimes in the .h.  To me it seems like what I see is declare it in the .m if you can, if you have to put it in the .h, put it there instead, and if you can use a forward declaration for a class, then do that.  Just not sure what the proper way to do things are.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"declare it in the .m if you can, if you have to put it in the .h, put it there instead, and if you can use a forward declaration for a class, then do that." - I would say this *is* the proper way to do that.